# how do I open read-only excel from python using win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com, pythoncom

I need to open an xls file from python using win32com as read-only and I seem not be getting the effect I desire

Here is what I do:

```
import win32com

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_path, ReadOnly=1) # 1 is for readonly
```

The workbook opens and data shows; however, the file is not opened as read-only.
per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) argument signature should trigger read-only effect but it does not.

Anyone had to deal with similar problem before?

Comment: What do you need to get from the workbook? Table of information?

Comment: Although there are better ways to access an Excel document than using win32com, try setting `ReadOnly` to `True` instead of `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadyOnly` is a third parameter according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia).
Pass `None` for the `UpdateLinks` and True for `ReadyOnly`.

```
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_path, None, True)
```

Comment: @EyIM,
Thank you very much!    that was exactly what I was missing.  I have gotten way too used to named parameters in python...Thanks again!!